# On splitting XHTML into chapters with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xhtml, xslt-2.0

I have the following XSLT 2.0 code to split an XHTML file into chapters:

```
<xsl:for-each-group
  select=".//html:*[local-name() eq $chapter-tag][1]/(.|following-sibling::*)"
  group-starting-with="html:*[local-name() eq $chapter-tag]">
  ...
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

(here `$chapter-tag` is either `h1` or `h2`).

But this code does not work for the following XHTML fragment:

```
<div class="header">
  <h1>Header</h1>
</div>
<p>...</p>
...
```

Please help to do the right thing when the header is "buried" inside other tags.

### Complete example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header">
        <h1>First chapter</h1>
      </div>
      <p>First chapter text.</p>
      <p>Blah, blah, blah...</p>
      <div class="header">
        <h1>Second chapter</h1>
      </div>
      <p>Second chapter text.</p>
      <p>Blah, blah, blah...</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This should create the following element groups ("chapters"):

```
      <div class="header">
        <h1>First chapter</h1>
      </div>
      <p>First chapter text.</p>
      <p>Blah, blah, blah...</p>
```

and

```
      <div class="header">
        <h1>Second chapter</h1>
      </div>
      <p>Second chapter text.</p>
      <p>Blah, blah, blah...</p>
```

Comment: Consider to show minimal but complete snippets of an input sample and the corresponding output sample(s) so that we can understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: @MartinHonnen An example added

Comment: It seems that I need first find the deepest common ancestor of all `h1` (or `h2`) tags. But what to do then?

Comment: I also haven't yet figured how to find the deepest common ancestor

Comment: In the example in the question the deepest common ancestor is `<div class="container">`

Comment: The problem of finding deepest common ancestor is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8742002/856090

Comment: I don't think your question is defined well-enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
<xsl:template match="div[@class = 'container']">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="div[@class = 'header' and h1]">
     <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

then for your sample I think the task is solved. It all depends on how regular your input is.

Comment: `class="container"` was just an example. There is no reason to assume that the class will be namely `container`, neither that there is only one level of enclosed divs. Please remove your answer, it is wrong.

Comment: If you get a wrong answer from someone of Martin's calibre, it should tell you that there is something wrong with your question.

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure *exactly* what your requirement is, but would the pattern

```
group-starting-with="*[descendant-or-self::h1]"
```

help at all?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem in [my real code](https://github.com/vporton/htmlsplit). Now it works. Consult my code.

```
<xsl:template name="split">
  <xsl:variable name="container" select="my:lca(.//html:*[local-name() eq $chapter-tag])"/>
  <xsl:variable name="start" select="$container/node()[descendant-or-self::html:*[local-name() eq $chapter-tag]][1]"/> <!-- the first chapter header in the document -->
  <xsl:for-each-group select="$start|$start/following-sibling::node()"
                      group-starting-with="*[descendant-or-self::html:*[local-name() eq $chapter-tag]]">
    <!-- ... -->
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

`my:lca` user-defined function is defined in [Finding the lowest common ancestor of an XML node-set](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8742002/856090)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.